# Google Maps County & Postcode Borders in Javascript API 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I noted recently that google maps now includes a [border for a postcode](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=QUD&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1787&bih=861&q=nn14%201nj&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x48779fe1684f0783:0x5b7e36180d3218ba,Broughton%20NN14%201NJ&gl=uk&ei=xZJwT4iuI5Hm8QOioY3BDQ&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CCAQ8gEwAA) and [borders for a county](http://g.co/maps/axfu3)

Without creating a complete KML file myself, is this data not available from the API? I've been carefully watching the developers blogs as I really need the postcode data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that data is not available through the API.